# Could someone explain how Count works in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm making a table in SSRS that contains customer names in column 1 and their corresponding number of orders in column 2.  This query works for what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't know exactly how the Count function knows what the heck I want it to count and what table I'm wanting it to count from.  Could someone please explain this to me so I can better understand in the future?  Thanks a ton.

```
SELECT Customers.name
    ,Count(1) AS OrderCount
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Customers.id = Orders.customer_id
GROUP BY Customers.name
```

Comment: Should this really be tagged mysql? if you're using reporting services, you're more likely to want sql-server

Comment: this query counts every single record (`1` could be any other constant) for each unique customer name. What might be tricky to understand is how the `records` are defined. Keep in mind SQL first computes the sets (tables joined with each other) and then *projects* the results so it can be used in the select clause. The `count` does not make exception and counts `records` from this resultset, even though there would be 5 tables involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't know exactly how the Count function knows what the heck I want it to count

There is only one thing that `COUNT` is able to count - it can count *rows* in which an expression evaluates to a non-null value. If you use `COUNT(1)` in a regular query, you would get `1` on each row. With `GROUP BY`, however, the `COUNT` will return the number of rows *in the specific group*. In your case, that would be the number of rows with the same `Customers.name`, because that is what you use for `GROUP BY`.

As far as passing `1` to `COUNT` goes, a more common practice these days is to pass an asterisk, i.e. to write `COUNT(*)`, because in most RDBMS engines there is no performance penalty for that.

Comment: It can also count not null column values. The number of which may differ from the number of rows.

Comment: Could you actually describe what the difference between passing the `1` and the `*` is? What do they actually do?

Answer (score 2):

Count is counting `true` for each record found.  Therefore, if there are 3 records, it is counting `true` 3 times and returns `3`.  It doesn't really matter what it is counting in there as long as it exists or is a constant.  If it exists, it is counted.  It's the number of rows that you are being grouped when you group by that matters.

Answer (score -3):

it counts number of occurences of the first field in the result set